# In Brouwer's fixed point theorem, is the function $h(x)$ injective?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, functions

Is the function $h$ injective given [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brouwer%27s_Fixed_Point_Theorem/Smooth_Mapping) in Brouwer's fixed point theorem?
I have an intuition that it is injective by geometric construction. Formally, we need prove that $h(x)=h(y)$ implies $x=y$, that is,
$$tx+(1-t)f(x)=ty+(1-t)f(y),$$
implies that $x=y$ for all $x,y\in B.$

I can write $x$ and $y$ component wise as $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n),f(x)=(f(x_1),f(x_2),...,f(x_n))$,
then we need to prove that
$$tx_i+(1-t)f(x_i)=ty_i+(1-t)f(y_i)$$
implies $x_i=y_i$ for all $i$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that $t$ in the equation $$h(x) = tx + (1-t) f(x),$$
depends implicitly on $x$. So you actually have a $t_x$ and $t_y$ in your equations.

If you look at the definition of $h(x) = \partial B^n \cap L$, you notice that $h : B^n \to \partial B^n$. Furthermore, for $x \in \partial B^n$, we have $h(x) = x$. Thus $h$ cannot be injective as for any $y$ in the interior of $B^n$, we have $h(y) \in \partial B^n$ and thus $h(h(y)) = h(y)$ while $h(y) \neq y$.

Answer (score 2):

In its present form your question does not make much sense.

1. The intention is to give a *proof by contradiction* that there does not exist a fixed-point free (smooth) $f : B^n  \to B^n$. Under the assumption that we are given a fixed-point free $f$ one constructs a retraction $h : B^n \to \partial B^n$ (which cannot exist).
   According to the link in your question one has
   $$h(x) = tx + (1-t)f(x)$$
   where $t \in \mathbb  R$ has to satisfy the conditions $t \ge 1$ and $\lvert h(x) \rvert = 1$. As the "solution" one can find
   $$t = \frac{f(x) \cdot(f(x)-x)}{\lvert f(x) -x \rvert^2} .$$
   This is false. For the correct solution see [Continuous function on closed unit ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803499) and [Proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorem in Hatcher](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4540516).
2. Although there does not exist a fixed-point free smooth $f : B^n \to B^n$ (in fact not even a continuous $f$), we can consider a fixed-point free function $f : B^n \to B^n$ which is not required to be smooth or continuous and ask whether the associated $h$ is injective.
   But your interpretation
   "that is,
   $$tx+(1-t)f(x)=ty+(1-t)f(y)$$
   implies that $x=y$ for all $x,y\in B$"
   really does not make sense. You have to work with the specific values $t_x$ and $t_y$ determined in 1. and to ask whether
   $$h(x) = t_xx+(1-t_x)f(x)=t_yy+(1-t_y)f(y) = h(y)$$
   implies that $x=y$.
   Hetebrij's answer shows that this is **not the case** without using the explicit formula for $h(x)$.
3. Your "real" question is this: Given a set $M$, a subset $M_0 \subset M$ and a function $h : M \to M_0$ such that $h(x) = x$ for all $x \in M_0$. Is $h$ injective?
   The answer is trivially *yes* if $M_0 = M$ and *no* if $M_0 \ne M$. In the latter case pick $\xi \in M \setminus M_0$. Then $\xi' = h(\xi) \in M_0$, thus $\xi' \ne \xi$ and $h(\xi') = \xi' = h(\xi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Why would $h$ be injective? Suppose that $n=2$, that $f(0,0)=\left(\frac12,0\right)$ and that $f\left(\frac12,0\right)=\left(\frac23,0\right)$. Then$$h\left(\frac12,0\right)=h(0,0)=(-1,0).$$

Comment: @AnneBauval I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Do you have an idea why my answer was instantaneously downvoted thrice? I answered that because any "counterexample" like your $f$ seems cheating to me, since (by that theorem itself) it cannot extend to a map from the ball into itself without fixed point, hence it actually cannot give rise to any $h.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Sure: no real counterexample can exist. Concerning the downvotes that you got (none of which is mine), I think that that is due to the fact that what you wrote is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation led me to hopefully reformulate more clearly as an answer.

Comment: Several times I used formulations like "the downvotes that you got (none of which is mine)" in comments to the - justified! - amazement about downvotes. It seems that I was afraid (as José) that writing a comment raises the suspicion that I was a downvoter. But isn't it an unnecessary reflex to make such a disclaimer? Downvoters always remain anonymous and do not explain their reasons.